# CI/CD pipeline for a private cluster

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, cicd

How can i create a CI/CD pipeline for a private cluster in GCP?

Note: can u suggest some documentations or articles about that. There are not much articles about that

Actually there are few networkd which are authorized in my private cluster. when i pushing my code in github my private cluster is not accessible.

Comment: your question is too broad, try to ask more specific question

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear. What are trying to achieve exactly ? A CI/CD pipeline will work on a private cluster the same way it will work on a Public one.

If you CI/CD pipeline needs to talk to resources outside GCP, you can deploy a Cloud NAT to allow the cluster to talk to the internet.

Comment: Actually there are few networkd which are authorized in my private cluster. when i pushing my code in github my private cluster is not accessible.

Comment: Are you using github actions as a CI/CD pipeline ?